# How to convert application/atom+xml response to json using rest template

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am consuming atom/xml and i need to convert it to java object.
code is as below , i am getting conversion error

code:

```
 ResponseEntity<BusinessPartner> response = restTemplate.exchange(url + "/BP_HEADERSet('100000010')", HttpMethod.GET, entity, BusinessPartner.class);
```

error:

```
"message": "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.leaseplan.insuranceaccounting.models.BusinessPartner] and content type [application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8;type=entry]",
```

`BusinessPartner` is my custom class. and from url, i get the response as atom format `<content type="application/xml">`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter` and `RssChannelHttpMessageConverter` to rest template. 
Have a look at the code:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder templateBuilder) {
    return templateBuilder
            .additionalMessageConverters(
                    new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter(), 
                    new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter())
            .build();
}
```